# Display Woo commerce Products in Gravity Form Multi select Drop down

Tags: woocommerce, gravity-forms-plugin

I am creating a multipage form using gravity forms and need to ask that is it possible to display woocommerce products in gravity forms multiselect dropdown fields with images and price

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what you're trying to do with the form exactly but you can use [Gravity Perks Populate Anything](https://gravitywiz.com/documentation/gravity-forms-populate-anything/) to add your Woocommerce Products and prices (not sure about thumbnail) to a multi-select field.

If you want to purchase something using the form, you may want to embed the multipage form into the Woocommerce Product using the [Gravity Forms Woocommerce Product Addon](https://woocommerce.com/products/gravity-forms-add-ons/) instead.